# How can I change the default font of Outlook 2016?

Tags: outlook, fonts, vbscript, html-email, office-automation

I want to change the default Arial Font type to Montserrat in Microsoft Office (not the 365).

I'm following what is presented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4a0b8dc4-d74c-4f1b-84be-4a5c2f187b87/vbscript-to-change-font-size?forum=ITCG). I was also told that I should try running it in PowerShell but I have no idea how.

The following is what I created so far:

```
Sub ChangeFont()
    Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim NewTask As Outlook.TaskItem 
    Set objOLApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set NewTask = objOLApp.CreateItem(0)

    with Newtask
        .DefaultFont = "Montserrat"
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
END Sub

WScript.Echo "Done!"

pause

exit
```

When save it as a .vbs file and double-click on that, I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, vbScript does not allow type declaration, e.g. `As Outlook.Application`. Declare only the variable names and change `Set objOLApp = New Outlook.Application` to `Set objOLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`.

Comment: If you don't have outlook installed, how could the VBScript environment create an Outlook object?

Comment: @FunThomas I currently, don't have it installed on my personal device but I could test it later on another device that has Outlook. Sorry for the confusion, should've mentioned it. I'll edit my post.

Comment: The code provided is not VBScript. If this is meant to be a VBScript question [edit] it and show your VBScript code.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any default font properties like shown in the code sample. Instead, you can use the HTML markup to specify a custom font for the message body. For example:

```
olReply.HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:'Segoe UI'><p style='font-size:11px'>Hello, <p> The individuals(s) in the email below have been submitted to the customer today, " & strDate & olReply.HTMLBody
```

Or just use the Word object model like shown in the following sample VBA code:

```
Public WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Public WithEvents objInspector As Outlook.Inspector

Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInspectors = Outlook.Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Public Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
    Set objInspector = Inspector
End Sub

Public Sub objInspector_Activate()
    Dim objCurrentItem As Object
    Dim objCurrentInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document
    Dim objWordSelection As Word.Selection
 
    Set objCurrentItem = objInspector.CurrentItem
    Set objCurrentInspector = objCurrentItem.GetInspector
    Set objWordDocument = objCurrentInspector.WordEditor
    Set objWordSelection = objWordDocument.Application.Selection
 
    'You change the font as per your preference
    Select Case objCurrentItem.Class
           Case olContact
                With objWordSelection.Font
                     .Name = "Segoe Script"
                     .ColorIndex = wdRed
                     .Size = 8
                     .Bold = True
                End With
           Case olAppointment
                With objWordSelection.Font
                     .Name = "Comic Sans MS"
                     .ColorIndex = wdBlue
                     .Size = 9
                     .Bold = False
                End With
           Case olTask
                With objWordSelection.Font
                     .Name = "MV Boli"
                     .ColorIndex = wdGreen
                     .Size = 10
                     .Bold = True
                End With
   End Select
End Sub
```

The [Inspector.WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed.

Comment: I see, it seems like I may not have enough VB Script knowledge to understand the code above. However, as per the previous comment in the question, I think the syntax with **** As **** may not work. As per the HTLM custom font, do you have a resource for this? What I'm trying to create is an Outlook 2016 font change upon double-clinking a VB script. This will cover even the font of the existing emails like when it was initially formatted in Arial, it would change to TNR or any other. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Also sir, I want to ask if how do you run this file and test if it's successful?

Comment: The code posted was checked in VBA, so it has some minor syntax differences. I bet you can change these changes and adapt the code to the vbscript environment because the Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages.

Comment: You can debug and test the code in VBA prior getting it running in VBScript.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and tried to convert it to a VBScript. However, it still do not work even if I have an open Outlook 2016 instance. As per the HTML body font change, I have no experience with VBA to understand how to implement this script unfotunately. Thanks for the help anyways. I'm trying to figure out how to automatically do this with other programming languages.

Comment: The Outlook and Word object model is common for all programming languages.

Comment: Yeag I get that, but I have no reference to follow on how to change the fonts programatically since I don't have experience with VBS or VBA. I was hoping if there is a way to do this easier in other languages like Python.

Comment: You can use the same sequence of property and method calls in python, as I wrote, the Outlook and Word object model is the same for all languages.