# Changing Font Type of Messages in Outlook when double-clicking a .vbs file

Tags: vba, outlook, vbscript, outlook-2016

I have no experience nor any idea about VB scripts but I was tasked to create a .vbs file wherein when I double-click that file, it will automatically change the default font in Outlook 2016 to Montserrat. I've been picking up the pieces of whatever resource I could find online but it seems that the scripts I'm making do not change anything particular nor any message that it really ran successfully. I'm basically double-clicking the .vbs scripts I made and nothing happens. Below is what I had so far but I was told that that the .DefaultFont feature is not supported.

```
Sub ChangeFont()
    Dim objOLApp
    Dim NewTask
    Set objOLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set NewTask = objOLApp.CreateItem(0)

    with Newtask
        .DefaultFont = "Montserrat"
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set objOLApp = Nothing
    Set NewTask = Nothing
END Sub
```

Basically what happens is when I run the script then open Outlook 2016, all the font configs will be set to Montserrat style like in the image below:

[image]

Is there any starting point anyone can recommend for this? Been stuck in this task for weeks. Thank you in advance.

I've already tried several code snippets I outsourced on the documentation and available resources online. Some kind-of makes sense to me but I'm not really sure how to match the pieces. I was expecting to create a .vbs file wherein when I double-click that file or open the file, the fonts of the running Outlook instance messages would change from the default font to Montserrat. I'm not really sure if this is possible but any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate questions, instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74400820/edit) the original and correct any issues that led you to post a duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicated post.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev explain what makes this different when the two questions are from the same OP, involve the exact same issue and are posted days apart?

Comment: The second post clarifies things that was not mentioned in the first one. I see the difference. The author understood the answer given on the first post and decided to ask more precise question.

Comment: So [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74400820/edit) the first one to add clarity, there is no justifiable argument for this approach. It is a duplicate question. That goes for the OPs question and your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the code you are creating a new `MailItem` instance, not a task item like it was named.

Second, Outlook items like `MailItem` or `TaskItem` don't provide the `DefaultFont` property.

Third, I've already described possible ways of changing the font-related properties in Outlook. Check out your post - [Automatically Change Default Font of Outlook 2016 using Visual Basic Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74400820/automatically-change-default-font-of-outlook-2016-using-visual-basic-script). In brief, you can use the HTML markup to specify a custom font or use the Word object model to deal with item bodies.

Fourth, you can find some Outlook settings in the Windows registry. So, to locate where exactly Outlook keeps Outlook settings I'd suggest using the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) utility, so you could do the required changes in the UI and track where they are saved.

You may also find similar questions posted over the internet, see [Set Font Style and Size of email message called from VB.net](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5629c6c5-65d4-4b00-86f2-5e4756b86162/set-font-style-and-size-of-email-message-called-from-vbnet?forum=outlookdev).

Comment: Instead of repeating yourself flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: They are different, sounds similar.

Comment: Different enough? I don’t think so, that is a flimsy argument.

Comment: Also VB.Net has no relation to VBScript, suggesting it just dilutes the question and will confuse the OP further.

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages.

Comment: VBA, VBScript, VB.NET - all of them have a similar syntax.

Comment: The syntax maybe similar but they are not the same. You could say JavaScript is similar to Java but they are very different beasts. As for Outlook, yes it is an object model and I never said otherwise.

Comment: VBA and VBScript tags were posted by the OP. I don't see any problems there.

Comment: The problem is this is just a regurgitation of an existing answer (which you go on to link to). Correct approach here would have been to flagged the question and move on. You also start mentioning VB.Net which is completely different technology and just adds further confusion.

Comment: Whatever technology is used, as I wrote you earlier, the Outlook object model is the same.